# Within-subject variability derived from an empty mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, residuals, variability

I run an empty mixed-effect model with an AR1 structure. My dataset included repeated measures of 20 subjects:

```r
model_empty <- lme(log(outcome) ~ 1, random = ~1 |Player, 
                   correlation = corAR1(form = ~ DaysSinceFirstTest),
                   control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 100),
                   data = mydata)
```

I'm interested in calculating within-subject variability expressed as the coefficient of variation (%). Currently, I've attempted to calculate it by dividing the residual standard deviation by the random intercept of each individual. However, as the residual SD is standard, the CV (%) is larger for individuals with a smaller intercept and smaller for those with a larger intercept. In reality, the variability across repeated measures shouldn't be influenced by the intercept. Is there a method to calculate the individual residual SD, if this makes sense?

Comment: does adding `weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Player)` help? Since you're already on the log scale, arguably you shouldn't be computing CVs anyway ... the variability associated with `log(outcome)` is already measuring variability on a scale **proportional** to `outcome` ...

Comment: Please make clear that you are using the `nlme` R package, e.g.  with`library(nlme)`

Comment: Apologies. Yes, I am using nlme R package.